# Complex events spread over years

Tags: wso2, apache-storm, apache-flink, complex-event-processing, wso2-streaming-integrator

I have a scenario whereby if part of a query matches an event, I want to fetch some other events from a datastore to test against the rest of the query

eg. "*If JANE DOE buys from my store did she buy anything else over last 3 years*" sort of thing.

Does Flink, Storm or WSO2 provide support for such complex event processing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Flink can do this, but it would require that you process all events starting from the earliest that you care about (e.g. 3 years ago), so that you can construct the state for each customer. Flink then lets you manage this state (typically with RocksDB) so that you wouldn't have to replay all the events in the face of system failures.

If you can't replay all of the history, then typically you'd put this into some other store (Cassandra/HBase, Elasticsearch, etc) with the scalability and performance characteristics you need, and then use Flink's async function support to query it when you receive a new event.

Answer (score 0):

[WSO2 Stream processor](https://wso2.com/analytics) let’s you implement such functionality with it’s time [incremental analytics](https://docs.wso2.com/display/SP410/Incremental+Analysis) feature. To implement the scenario you’ve mentioned you can feed the events that are triggered when a customer arrives to an construct called ‘aggregate’.  When you keep feeding events to an aggregate it will summarize data over time and will saved in a configured persistence store such as DB.

You can query this aggregate to get the state for a given period of time. For an example  following query will fetch the name, total items bought and avg transaction value with the year 2014-2015

```
from CustomerSummaryRetrievalStream as b join CustoemrAggregation as a
on a.name == b.name
within "2014-01-01 00:00:00 +05:30", "2015-01-01 00:00:00 +05:30"
per “years”
select a.name, a.total, a.avgTxValue
insert into CustomerSummaryStream;
```